# Getting an UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning when posting to a NodeJS backend

Tags: node.js

Need a little help. Been learning NodeJS. And so far so good. But I am running into an issue when I try to create a new ToDo object that's associated with an authenticated user.

I get the following error

> (node:54162) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
>   (node:54162) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Here is the offending code:

```
app.post('/todos', authenticate, (req, res) => {
var todo = new Todo({
    text: req.body.text,
    _creator: req.user._id
});
todo.save().then(() => {
    res.send(todo);     
 }).catch((e) => {
     res.status(400).send(e);
 });
})
```

I am not sure what I am missing. I've read in certain places about try catch mismatches. But I am still not sure.

Just for more context, I have also added my authenticate.js

```
var {User} = require('./../models/user');

//Definining endpoint authentication middleware
var authenticate = (req, res, next) => {
    var token = req.header('x-auth');
    User.findByToken(token).then((user) => {
        if(!user) {
            return Promise.reject();
        }
        req.user = user;
        req.token = token;
        next();
        res.send(user);
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.status(401).send();
    }); 
};

module.exports = {authenticate};
```

Comment: The only ways I can see that the code you show would cause such an error are: 1) If `new Todo()` throws or 2) If `res.send(e)` throws or 3) `authenticate(req, res, next)` throws.  It seems most likely that the problem would be in `authenticate()`.  Can you show that code?  Also, what is `Todo()`?

Comment: Certainly. I have updated my question.

Comment: I don't know.  I think you're going to have to put `console.log()` statements all throughout this code and find where it's throwing/rejecting because I don't see anything obvious.  My current guess is that the message comes from something other than what we have code for here.

Comment: One thing that is not correct, but would not cause the warning you are asking about is where you do `next()` and then `res.send(user)`.  You should not be doing both.  One or the other.  If you want the routing to continue to the next in the routing chain, then use `next()`, but don't do `res.send()`.